# Lightning Component in Flow - How to disable Next Button?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, button

I have a simple flow with a Lightning Component, I need to not allow the user to click to flow button until he click on a button in the lightning component itself.
Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the field they are clicking 'required', this would not allow the user to advance through the flow without an input.